# how i can display some UI e.g circle and when data arrives i can change the color of specific circle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, react-hooks

I am working on a project in which

1- i have to display 50 circle on screen.
2- My data is streaming in real time.
data in form of object in which i am storing {id:0,color:"red"}.
So for example if id in real time data  is {id:10,color:"pink"}.
then the circle number 10 color should be pink.for Simplicity I am generating a custom hook for generating a random number.
//RandomNumber() is custom hook.

```
  const [random,setRandom]=RandomNumber();
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(random);
    if(random>10 && random<200)
    {
        setColor("Red")
    }
   else if(random>500)
    {
     setColor("brown")
    }

})
return (
<div className="show-data" onWheel={onWheelHandler}>
{
        

            Array.apply(null, { length: 50 }).map((a, i) => (
             
                pad=="60px"?

                <button className="wave-circle"  style={{backgroundColor:color,padding:pad}}   onMouseOver={onMouseOverHandler}  onClick={onClickHandler} onMouseOut={onMouseLeaveHandle }  key={i}>
                
                {i+1} 
                
                </button>
                :
                <button className="wave-circle"  style={{backgroundColor:color,padding:pad}} value={i+1}   onMouseOver={onMouseOverHandler} onClick={onClickHandler} onMouseOut={onMouseLeaveHandle}  key={i}>
                </button>
        
            ) ,  

            )    
}
```

Comment: (1) the array of "circle" data would need to be stored in state, (2) each time streaming data is processed map the old array to a new array and update the specific element by matching id.

Comment: can you code some so that i can understand better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) the array of "circle" data would need to be stored in state, (2) each time streaming data is processed map the old array to a new array and update the specific element by matching id.

Example:

```
function App() {
  const [circles, setCircles] = React.useState(
    Array.from({ length: 50 }, (_, id) => ({
      id,
      color: "red"
    }))
  );

  // Simulate data on interval
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const tick = () => {
      setCircles((circles) => {
        const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * circles.length);
        return circles.map((c) => (c.id === id ? { ...c, color: "brown" } : c));
      });
    };

    const timer = setInterval(tick, 250);

    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {circles.map(({ id, color }) => (
        <div key={id} className="circle" style={{ backgroundColor: color }} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-i-can-display-some-ui-e-g-circle-and-when-data-arrives-i-can-change-the-colo]